# How to get all the paths of exe in my computer with c#

Tags: c#

Yes there any way by which i can get the paths of exe? I mean suppose i have 20 exes in my local disk c i want to get the paths of the exe like "C:\myexe.exe or it can be C:\dir\myexe.exe"

```
string getpathforexe[] = themethord;
foreach(string printvalue in getpathforexe)
{
     messagebox.show(printvalue.tostring());
}
```

so what will be themethord?

Comment: Hint: look at the `Directory` class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory

Comment: Is it Directory.GetFiles Method (String, String, SearchOption)?

Comment: Well have you tried it?

Comment: ya but its giving unauthorized access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you essentially need is a safe, recursive, `.exe` search functions on a root folder, and you can apply it anywhere.

Something like this:

```
public static List<string> GetAllAccessibleFiles(string path, string searchPattern) {
    List<string> dirPathList = new List<string>();
    try {
        string[] childFilePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        dirPathList.AddRange(childFilePaths);
        foreach (string childDirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(path)) { //foreach child directory, do recursive search
            List<string> grandChildDirPath = GetAllAccessibleFiles(childDirPath, searchPattern);
            if (grandChildDirPath != null && grandChildDirPath.Count > 0) //this child directory has children and nothing has gone wrong
                dirPathList.AddRange(grandChildDirPath); //add the grandchildren to the list
        }
        return dirPathList; //return the whole list found at this level
    } catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex){
        //Do something if necessary
        return null; //something has gone wrong, return null
    }
}
```

Be careful of a couple of things:

1. Not all directories are accessible. When you try to access an unaccessible directory, you would get `UnauthorizedAccessException`
2. By using recursive search, you want your search result to be failed *only* on the directory where you have no access right.

Nevertheless, if you apply this to all your folders, likely you will take very long time. It is best to apply it to particular folders which you want to search for `.exe` files.

**Explanations:**

In the function, given a path, if first lists the files in the directory top folder:

```
string[] childFilePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
dirPathList.AddRange(childFilePaths);
```

If any of your files matches your search pattern, you add those files. Then next you check each folder consisted in your path directory:

```
foreach (string childDirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(path)) { //foreach child directory, do recursive search
    List<string> grandChildDirPath = GetAllAccessibleFiles(childDirPath, searchPattern);
    if (grandChildDirPath != null && grandChildDirPath.Count > 0) //this child directory has children and nothing has gone wrong
        dirPathList.AddRange(grandChildDirPath); //add the grandchildren to the list
}
```

If any of the directory consists of any child folders, do recursive search to the children directories, and add the results together in the `dirPathList` and finally returns it:

```
return dirPathList; //return the whole list found at this level
```

Then you could get all the files with `".exe"`.

And in the catch, you probably want to check for the unauthorized access Exception:

```
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex){
    //Do something
    return null; //something has gone wrong, return null
}
```

You use it like this:

```
List<string> exefiles = YourClassNameWhoHasTheMethod.GetAllAccessibleFiles(testfolder, "*.exe"));
```

For example, you could test it with Recycle Bin like this:

```
string rbin = @"C:\$Recycle.Bin";
List<string> files = GetAllAccessibleFiles(rbin, "*.exe");
```

And these are what I get for the files:

```
C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-3161714743-1342575415-982792061-1001\$IYFMY6V.exe
C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-3161714743-1342575415-982792061-1001\$RYFMY6V.exe
```

Comment: This seems like quite a longwinded alternative to `Directory.GetFiles("c:\\", "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`...

Comment: I am afraid of non-accessible directories, Mr @JonSkeet. If we put `Directory.GetFiles("c:\\", "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`, then when one of the directory search fails, we cannot get the rests.

Comment: What makes you think `Directory.GetFiles` doesn't handle that already? (Note that you're using a `GetAllAccessibleDirectories` method without showing that... what does that do, and how?) (A bit of experimentation shows it really *doesn't* handle it, which surprised me - but you should state that in your answer IMO, as well as showing how you'd avoid it.)

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right, I better explain what I have written further for clarity.

Comment: when i put this code try
            {
                //string getfiles = 
                //Directory.GetFiles("c:\\", "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                foreach (string getvalue in Directory.GetFiles("c:\\", "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(getvalue);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("sorry");
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }                //it givis me unauthorized access

Comment: Anyone please help me with this out

Comment: thanks lan but i dont know why there is an error in your code in x.Endswith(".exe")

Comment: @Ian: As I mentioned, it turns out that it *does* fail - at least on the recycle bin. I think that's valuable information to add to the answer.

Comment: While catching the exception works, I can't help but feel there should be a cleaner approach... and I'd certainly catch a *specific* exception rather than *everything*.

Comment: @JonSkeet updated with the specific exception for unauthorized access and example of using Recycle Bin. Again, thanks for your test and correction.

Comment: thnx for the suggestion but i want every exe how can i make that?

Comment: @arn48 simply change your root folder where you search, say, to `C:\ `. There is a `path` argument in the function. Set it right. You may also want to learn more about `Directory` class

Comment: @Ian Thanx a lot i am very grateful to you its nothing just perfect

Comment: Can you just do me a favor can u tell me one thing how can i get the names of every local disk

Comment: @arn48 glad that I can be of any help. ;) but please make sure that next time you do sufficient research before asking question. Seeing how many are the downvotes in your question, I guess the question is not too welcomed. If you put significant research amount in your question, I am sure the community will be more appreciative. Anyway, glad that you solve your issue. :)